# Linked list implementation in classes c++, showing Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I know the segmentation fault is occurring in this while loop: (`while(temp != NULL){temp = temp->next;}`), but I have no idea why.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class zDepthList {

        typedef struct node {
                int data;
                node* next;
                node* prev;
        } Node;

public:

        zDepthList() {
                head = NULL;
        }

        zDepthList(int array[], int length) {

                Node *temp, *ptr;
                int i = 0;

                while(i != length - 1) {
                        temp = head;
                        ptr = new Node;
                        ptr->data = array[i];
                        i++;
                        ptr->next = NULL;

                        if(head == NULL) {
                                head = ptr;
                                ptr->prev = NULL;
                        }

                        else {
                                while(temp != NULL) {
                                        temp = temp->next;
                                }
                        }
                        temp->next = ptr;
                        ptr->prev = temp;
                }
        }

        void out(const char order) {

                cout << head->data << endl;

        return;
        }

private:
        Node *head;
};
```

Comment: We need to see how you're using this class in your main program.

Comment: We're not supposed to do your (home)work for you.

Comment: my main passes an array of 30 elements and the length of the array(zDepthList z(l, 30);). the it calls out function(z.out('f')).

Comment: I did, and I also recoded the whole program. The seg fault is occurring in the while loop which does temp = temp->next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you have to initialize the `head` to `NULL`.

And after this while loop

```
                    else {
                            while(temp != NULL) {
                                    temp = temp->next;
                            }
                    }
                    temp->next = ptr;
                    ptr->prev = temp;
```

the pointer `temp` is equal to `NULL` because it is the condition to interrupt the loop. Thus this statement

```
                    temp->next = ptr;
```

results in undefined behavior.

If you have a double-linked list it is natural to introduce also data member `tail` that it could be easy to append new nodes.

So you should include

```
class zDepthList {
//...
private:
        Node *head, *tail;
};
```

In this case the constructors can look the following way

```
    zDepthList() : head( nullptr ), tail( nullptr )
    {
    }

    zDepthList( const int a[], size_t n ) : head( nullptr ), tail( nullptr )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            Node *tmp = new Node { a[i], nullptr, tail };
            tail == nullptr ? head = tmp : tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class zDepthList {

    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    } Node;

public:

    zDepthList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
    {
    }

    zDepthList(const int a[], size_t n) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Node *tmp = new Node{ a[i], nullptr, tail };
            tail == nullptr ? head = tmp : tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }


    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        for (Node *current = head; current; current = current->next)
        {
            os << current->data << ' ';
        }

        return os;
    }

private:
    Node *head, *tail;
};

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    zDepthList l(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));

    l.out() << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got freaking roasted tho lol

Answer (score 1):

You never set `head` but you access it. This means it is uninitialized and this is an UB.

You have 2 ctors and you initialize `head` only then, when it is called without any parameter.

Comment: `head` is set in the constructor

Comment: I set head to NULL at the start of second constructor but the seg fault still exists.

Comment: If `head` is `NULL`, you still do `temp = head` and then `temp->next = ptr`  with `NULL` `temp`. Dereferencing null pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @aashman Please update your code. In the current version you do **not** set it.